# Pass the value of currentTextChanged

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt5

Following is a piece of code.

Currently the `combobox` is managed by `self.Cbox.btn.clicked.connect(self.Goto_Analyze)`.

I would like to avoid the `btn` and use `currentTextChanged` but wherever I put it I get an error.

```
    self.MyCbox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.My_tab)
    self.MyCbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 30, 100, 21))
    self.MyCbox.setObjectName("MyCbox")
    self.MyCbox.addItems(Functions.nbr)
    
    aa  = str(self.MyCbox.currentText())
    print(aa) # aa = 6
    self.Cbox.btnsetText(_translate("Library_main", "Select"))
    self.Cbox.btnclicked.connect(self.Goto_Analyze)
    


def Goto_Analyze(self, ): 
        aa = str(self.MyCbox.currentTextChanged())
        [...]
        some code


File "../index.py", line 796, in Goto_Analyze
aa = str(self.MyCbox.currentTextChanged())
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

Comment: Just change `self.Cbox.btnclicked.connect(self.Goto_Analyze)` to `self.MyCbox.currentTextChanged(self.Goto_Analyze)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `signal` so you need

```
currentTextChanged.connect(...)
```

like for signal `clicked` you need `clicked.connect(...)`

---

Minimal working code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        
        self.cbox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)  # PEP8: `lower_case_name` for variables
        self.cbox.addItems([str(x) for x in range(3)])

        self.cbox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.goto_analyze)

    def goto_analyze(self, value):  # PEP8: `lower_case_name` for functions
        print(type(value), value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)